# ChoiceField: choices are formed only at Django start

Tags: django

**Django 1.11.4**

My code is below.
The problem is that it executes only once: at the Django start.
I'd like people to renew when the web page is reloaded.
Could you help me with this?

**forms.py**

```
def get_people_choices():
    people = Person.objects.all()
    choices = [(None, "----")]
    choices += [(person.id, person) for person in people]
    return choices

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    person_choice = forms.ChoiceField(label='', choices=get_people_choices(), required=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should recycle code using model `ModelChoiceField`. Is very simple following your example should be something like:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    person_choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Person.objects.all)
```

it will return in your template:

```
<select id="id_field1" name="field1">
<option value="person1.pk">person1</option>
<option value="person2.pk">person2</option>
...
</select>
```

if you want to change the value, add `(queryset=..., to_field_name="name")` and now the value will be the name of the person or whatever you want.

If you want to see more [check this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `__init__` for the field:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['person_choice'] = forms.ChoiceField(label='', choices=get_people_choices(), required=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is to pass the callable `get_people_choices`, instead of calling it in the form definition.

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    person_choice = forms.ChoiceField(label='', choices=get_people_choices, required=False)
```

This will work with Django 1.8+. For earlier versions, you would have to override the `__init__` method, as in Bear Brown's answer.

It might be a better idea to use a `ModelChoiceField`, as Mauricio suggests.